# Getting range is too small for min.n error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make  a line graph of some performance data that I have collected using R. I want to graph each cpu and the total. I have a Names column in my txt file and I try set that to the color since they are factors. However I get this error `Error in prettyDate(x = x, n = n, min.n = min.n, sep = sep, ...) : 
  range too small for min.n`
Here is my code.

```
library(ggplot2)
setwd("../../../PerfLogs")
cpu<-read.delim("CPUUsage.txt", header=FALSE, sep="\t")
names(cpu)<-c("Date", "Name", "Usage")
dates<-as.character(cpu$Date)
dates<-strptime(cpu$Date, "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
cpu$Date<-dates
graph<-ggplot(cpu, aes(cpu$Date, cpu$Usage, colour=cpu$Name)) + geom_line(size=1.0)
graph
```

Here is some sample data from CPUUsage.txt

```
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    0   0
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    1   18
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    2   6
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    3   18
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    4   6
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    5   18
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    6   6
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    7   6
2/13/2013 1:37:17 PM    _Total  10
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    0   16
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    1   5
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    2   28
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    3   0
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    4   22
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    5   5
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    6   5
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    7   16
2/13/2013 1:37:18 PM    _Total  12
```

The middle column is Name and the right column is Usage. I was hoping since it used factors it wouldn't matter if the date / times were exactly the same

Comment: It would be best to use `dput(head())` rather than pasting data in this instance as your time column will make it frustrating for people to use `read.table(text=` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is due to fact that your x values are `datetime` and difference between two values is just one second (too small to show data). You have to use `scale_x_datetime()` and set `breaks` to `"1 sec"` to show your data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(cpu, aes(Date, Usage, colour=Name)) + 
   geom_line(size=1) + 
   scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 sec"))
```

[image]