# Bar chart with only a single x value on datetime axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

In reference to the code below:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
df = data.frame(x=now(),y=1)
ggplot(data=df,aes(x,y)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

The following error is thrown:

```
 Error in prettyDate(x = x, n = n, min.n = min.n, sep = sep, ...) : 
  range too small for 'min.n'
```

Which is the appropriate way to handle a bar chart on a timescale with only a single `x` value?

This is my `sessionInfo()`, ggplot and lubridate have just been updated to latest version via `install.packages(...)`

```
R Under development (unstable) (2015-08-14 r69078)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)

locale:
[1] en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8/C/en_AU.UTF-8/en_AU.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.1.0   lubridate_1.5.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6  scales_0.3.0.9000 plyr_1.8.3        magrittr_1.5      tools_3.3.0       gtable_0.1.2.9000 Rcpp_0.12.3      
 [8] stringi_1.0-1     grid_3.3.0        stringr_1.0.0     munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this error, can you check your package versions?

Comment: Unable to replicate the error as @Shorpy has mentioned.

Comment: I have just added my sessioninfo, I am using latest versions of ggplot2 and lubridate.

Comment: Same here, cannot reproduce the error. R version 3.3.0, ggplot2_2.1.0, lubridate_1.5.6.

Comment: Maybe duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860921

Comment: I had a similar problem with base graphics.  I was able to avoid the problem  by manually setting the limits on the x-axis as opposed to having the plot command calculate them.

Answer (score 1):

Try coercing `x` to a string using `as.character()`, either as it's inserted into `df`, or as it's inserted into the call to `aes()`.  This will bypass ggplot's usual tendency to split datetime ranges into clean scales for graphical output.  So you'd use:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(as.character(x),y)) +
   geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Or, if you don't need the time part of the datetime, you can coerce `x` to a date using `as.Date()`, and ggplot will happily accept this.

Hope this helps!!