# Error in prettyDate range too small for min.n in ggplot2 facet chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I have a dataset with all the olympics results in athletics.
I need to make a facet ggplot with different categories, for example 100m and Marathon so i subset:

```
ath.sub <- subset(ath, Event_STD%in%c('100m','Marathon'))
```

i got this dataframe

```
> head(ath.sub)
Event Event_STD          Athlete Country Result  Medal YEAR unit Sex       time
1261 100m Men      100m       Usain Bolt     JAM   9.69   GOLD 2008 time Men 2011-01-01
1262 100m Men      100m   Donovan Bailey     CAN   9.84   GOLD 1996 time Men 2011-01-01
1263 100m Men      100m    Justin Gatlin     USA   9.85   GOLD 2004 time Men 2011-01-01
1264 100m Men      100m Francis Obikwelu     POR   9.86 SILVER 2004 time Men 2011-01-01
1265 100m Men      100m   Maurice Greene     USA   9.87   GOLD 2000 time Men 2011-01-01
1266 100m Men      100m   Maurice Greene     USA   9.87 BRONZE 2004 time Men 2011-01-01
> tail(ath.sub)
Event Event_STD            Athlete Country  Result  Medal YEAR unit   Sex                time
3370 Marathon Women  Marathon Valentina Yegorova     RUS 2:28.05 SILVER 1996 time Women 2011-01-01 02:28:00
3371 Marathon Women  Marathon       Yuko Arimori     JPN 2:28.39 BRONZE 1996 time Women 2011-01-01 02:28:00
3372 Marathon Women  Marathon Valentina Yegorova     URS 2:32:41   GOLD 1992 time Women 2011-01-01 02:32:00
3373 Marathon Women  Marathon       Yuko Arimori     JPN 2:32:49 SILVER 1992 time Women 2011-01-01 02:32:00
3374 Marathon Women  Marathon    Lorraine Moller     NZL 2:33.59 BRONZE 1992 time Women 2011-01-01 02:33:00
3375 Marathon Women  Marathon  Catherine Ndereba     KEN    <NA> SILVER 2008 time Women                <NA>
> str(ath.sub)
'data.frame':   236 obs. of  10 variables:
$ Event    : chr  "100m Men" "100m Men" "100m Men" "100m Men" ...
$ Event_STD: chr  "100m" "100m" "100m" "100m" ...
$ Athlete  : chr  "Usain Bolt" "Donovan Bailey" "Justin Gatlin" "Francis Obikwelu" ...
$ Country  : chr  "JAM" "CAN" "USA" "POR" ...
$ Result   : chr  "9.69" "9.84" "9.85" "9.86" ...
$ Medal    : chr  "GOLD" "GOLD" "GOLD" "SILVER" ...
$ YEAR     : int  2008 1996 2004 2004 2000 2004 1996 2008 1996 2008 ...
$ unit     : chr  "time" "time" "time" "time" ...
$ Sex      : chr  "Men" "Men" "Men" "Men" ...
$ time     : chr  "2011-01-01 00:00:09.69" "2011-01-01 00:00:09.84" "2011-01-01 00:00:09.85" "2011-01-01 00:00:09.86" ...
```

then i convert the time field in posixct

```
> ath.sub$time<-as.POSIXct(ath.sub$time,tz = 'GMT')
> str(ath.sub$time)
POSIXct[1:236], format: "2011-01-01 00:00:00" "2011-01-01 00:00:00" "2011-01-01 00:00:00" "2011-01-01 00:00:00" ...
```

As i wrote before i need to make a ggplot facet line chart.
If i choose similar disciplines (like 100m or 400m) i've no problems.
But with different time discipliens like 100m and marathon i got this error

```
Error in prettyDate(x = x, n = n, min.n = min.n, sep = sep, ...) :
```

range too small for 'min.n'

here is the ggplot code

```
gg.ath<- ggplot(ath.sub, aes( YEAR, time, colour=Sex))+
facet_wrap(~Event_STD, scales = 'free')+
scale_y_datetime()+
scale_x_continuous(breaks = ath.sub$YEAR)+
geom_line()+
geom_smooth()
```

Comment: possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860921/getting-range-is-too-small-for-min-n-error ?

Comment: no, i tried it but it's a different problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleague fixed it, she used lubridate package while converting the time field

```
ath.sub$time <- lubridate::ymd_hms(ath.sub$time)
```